# Inserting a node at the end of linked list, .exe crashes

Tags: c, doubly-linked-list

i'm trying to make a simple program where i have insert quiz questions into a linked list.
The code crashes at: `novo->nodo=info;`

```
void InserirFim(ELEMENTO **iniLista, ELEMENTO **fimLista, INFO info){
    ELEMENTO *novo=NULL;
    novo=(ELEMENTO *)calloc(1,sizeof(ELEMENTO));
    if(novo=NULL){
        printf("ERROR ao reservar a memoria \n");
        return;
}
    novo->nodo=info;
    novo->anterior=NULL;
    novo->seguinte=NULL;


    if(*iniLista==NULL){
        *iniLista=novo;
        *fimLista=novo;
    }
    else{
        novo->anterior=*fimLista;
        (*fimLista)->seguinte=novo;
        *fimLista=novo;

    }
    return;
}
```

All the variables that the nodes carries aren't null.

I'm sorry for the code being in Portuguese, but novo stands for new, anterior stands for before and seguinte stands for next.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems is just a small bug in:

```
if(novo=NULL){
```

It should be:

```
if(novo==NULL){
```